# How to change a GCP pub/sub subscription filter in production?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, filter, publish-subscribe

I have a topic with a subscription with protocol pub/sub.  This subscription has a filter, we need to modify this filter to add new behaviour, it is in production.  So, I wondering if there is a way to modify this setting with less impact as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it is not possible to modify the filtering without deleting the subscription.

[image]

The only way for now is to delete the subscription then [create a new subscription with the new filter](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/filtering#creating_subscriptions_with_filters) that you want.

You can also submit a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests) about this, so it can be included in the future releases of pub sub.